# How to call optional function in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm trying to call an optional function included in an interface, but the function is not being called when I try to call it from a useEffect hook. These are my react componentes:

LikeButton.tsx:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { AppIcons } from "../../../images/base64/AppIcons";
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import GlobalContext from "../../../contexts/GlobalContext";

interface LikeCallback {
    callBackSaveLike?: (data?: any) => void;
    callBackDeleteLike?: (data?: any) => void;
};

const LikeButton = (props: any, callbacks?: LikeCallback) => {
    const {services} = useContext(GlobalContext);

    const [currentUserLikes, setCurrentUserLikes] = useState(false);
    const [refreshCountLikes, setRefreshCountLikes] = useState(false);
    const [countLikes, setCountLikes] = useState(0);

    const saveLikeHandler = (e: any) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        saveLike(props.ContentID, props.EntityType).then(response => {
            callbacks?.callBackSaveLike?.(response);
        });
    };

    const unLikeHandler = (e: any) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        unLike(props.ContentID, props.EntityType).then(response => {
            callbacks?.callBackDeleteLike?.(response);
        });
    };

    const saveLike = (contentId: any, entityType: any) => {
        return services.axero.saveLike(contentId, entityType).then(response => {
            setRefreshCountLikes(!refreshCountLikes);
            return response.json();
        });
    };

    const unLike = (contentId: any, entityType: any) => {
        return services.axero.saveUnLike(contentId, entityType).then(response => {
            setRefreshCountLikes(!refreshCountLikes);
            return response.json();
        });
    };

    // Loads likes count.
    useEffect(() => {
        services.axero.getContentLikeInfo(props.ContentID, props.EntityType).then(response => {
            setCountLikes(response.ResponseData.LikeCount);
            setCurrentUserLikes(response.ResponseData.DoesCurrentUserLikes);
        });
    }, [refreshCountLikes]);

    useEffect(() => {
        callbacks?.callBackSaveLike?.("FUNCTION CALLED!");
    }, []);

    return (
        <a href="#" className="likeContainer" onClick={currentUserLikes ? unLikeHandler : saveLikeHandler}>
        <img src={currentUserLikes ? AppIcons.LikeSelected : AppIcons.Like} alt="Heart"/>
        <span className="likeCount">{countLikes}</span>
    </a>
    );
};

export default LikeButton;
```

NewsArticle.tsx:

```
import * as React from "react";
import cliTruncate from 'cli-truncate';
import GlobalContext from "../../contexts/GlobalContext";
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Loc from "../../ServiceHelpers/Util/Loc";
import ReactHtmlParser from 'react-html-parser';
import moment = require("moment");
import TileFooter from "./sections/TileFooter";
import TileBody from "./sections/TileBody";
import TileHeader from "./sections/TileHeader";
import TileContainer from "./sections/TileContainer";
import BookMarkButton from "./buttons/BookMarkButton";
import LikeButton from "./buttons/LikeButton";

const NewsArticle = (props: any) => {
    const {services, loggedUserLanguageCode, translation} = useContext(GlobalContext);

    // Text values
    const [tileTitle, setTileTitle] = useState(props.ContentTitle);
    const [tileSummary, setTileSummary] = useState(props.ContentSummary);
    const [tileBody, setTileBody] = useState(cliTruncate(props.ContentBody, 100));
    const [fullTileBody, setFullTileBody] = useState(props.ContentBody);
    const [datePublished, setDatePublished] = useState(moment(props.DatePublished).format("YYYY/MM/DD h:mm a"));

    // Event handlers.
    const showFullBody = (e: any) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setTileBody(fullTileBody);
    };

    // Translations.
    useEffect(() => {
        services.translationService.sendTextForTranslation(translation.region, translation.key, loggedUserLanguageCode, [
            {
                "Text": tileTitle
            },
            {
                "Text": tileSummary
            },
            {
                "Text": fullTileBody
            },
            {
                "Text": datePublished
            }
        ]).then(response => {        
            setTileTitle(response[0].translations[0].text);
            setTileSummary(response[1].translations[0].text);
            setTileBody(cliTruncate(response[2].translations[0].text, 100));
            setFullTileBody(response[2].translations[0].text);
            setDatePublished(response[3].translations[0].text);
        });
    }, []);

    const callBackSaveBookMark = (data?: any) => {
        alert("SAVE");
    };

    const callBackDeleteBookMark = (data?: any) => {
        alert("DELETE");
    };

    const callBackSaveLike = (data?: any) => {
        alert("SAVE");
    };

    const callBackDeleteLike = (data?: any) => {
        alert("DELETE");
    };
  
    return (
        <TileContainer>
            <TileHeader props={...props}>
                <div className="tileHeaderImageAvatarContainer">
                    <img src={props.AuthorAvatarImageUrl} className="tileImageAvatar" alt="Logo"/>  
                </div>
                <div className="tileHeaderTitleSummary">
                    <div className="tileHeaderTitleContainer">
                        <div className="tileHeaderTitle">
                            <p>{tileTitle}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div className="tileHeaderDatePublished">
                            <p>
                                {datePublished}
                            </p> 
                        </div>                        
                    </div>
                    <div className="tileHeaderContentSummary">
                        <p>{tileSummary}</p>  
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </TileHeader>
            <TileBody {...props}>
                <img src={props.ContentFeaturedImageFullURL} className="tileBodyMainImage" alt="Default Blue Box"/>
                <div className="tileBodyContent">{ReactHtmlParser(tileBody)}</div>
            </TileBody>
            <TileFooter {...props}>
                <div className="footerIcons">
                    <BookMarkButton {...props} callbacks={{
                        callBackSaveBookMark: callBackSaveBookMark,
                        callBackDeleteBookMark: callBackDeleteBookMark
                    }}/>
                    <LikeButton {...props} callbacks={{
                        callBackSaveLike: callBackSaveLike,
                        callBackDeleteLike: callBackDeleteLike
                    }}/>
                </div>
                <div className="footerLearnMore">
                    <a href="#" onClick={showFullBody} className="footerLearnMoreText">{Loc("lblLearnMore", "Learn More")}</a>
                </div>  
            </TileFooter>
        </TileContainer>
            
    );

};

export default NewsArticle;
```

This line of code `callbacks?.callBackSaveLike?.("FUNCTION CALLED!");` is not being called. Do you have any idea why the function is not being called?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: the code you posted should be working, how do you know it's not being called?

Comment: @nullptr well, because the ```alert("SAVE");``` is not displayed. Please see the function callBackSaveLike in the NewsArticle component.

Comment: Сould you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)